# ada reserved word as identifier

Tags: types, ada

So i have a type that i declared and it refers to peoples names, and one of the names is "Do"
for example

```
type name is (BOB, SKIPPY, DO)
```

> Compiler error: reserved word "Do" cannot be used as identifier.

Is there anywhere around this without having to use strings? Seems like the teacher did this on purpose to force strings on us.

I made a generic package so would it be easier to make a variable string type and just instantiate that instead?

Answer (score 4):

A reserved word is a *reserved* word, end of story.

There's a handful of commonly employed techniques when a reserved word is the best word in a given situation:

- Prefix it, e.g. (Name_Bob, Name_Skippy, Name_Do);
- Suffix it, e.g. (Bob_Name, Skippy_Name, Do_Name);
- "Misspell" it, e.g. (Bob, Skippy, Do_Do);

If you're worried about how this will look if you output it, well, the naive enum-to-string attribute, 'Image, is usually discouraged since it's a literal depiction of the enumeration value, and therefore the content of your output becomes tightly coupled to your choice of coding identifiers. It's fine for debug, but for human-readable output you should use something else, like either casing on the enumeration value or using an enum-to-string Map.

Unless there's some compelling reason, there's nothing to be gained by using strings to represent the values of an enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Go with the prefix [or suffix] option and then you can do something like this:

```
type Names is ( Name_Bobby, Name_Dave, Name_Calvin, Name_Do );

Function Put( Item : In names ) Return String is
  Prolog : Constant String:= "Name_";
  Image  : Constant String:= Item'Image;
begin
  Return Image( Image'First+Prolog'Length..Image'Last );
end Put;
```